# Mysql IF NOT EXISTS then syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, not-exists

I can't manage to produce a working mysql query right now for what I want. I got as close as

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM Users 
              WHERE Downloads='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4') 
UPDATE Users 
SET `Downloads`='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4' 
WHERE `User`='andrewfree';
```

This fails, I was reading about INSERT IGNORE INTO but that hasn't helped either. What I am trying to do is add this hash to a users Download field if it doesn't exist in the table in anyones Download field.

Comment: SQL - Structured **Query** Language. It's not a programming language!

Comment: @Tomalak: According to wikipedia, it **IS** a programming language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: @ypercube: Then Wikipedia is wrong. Shock horror.

Comment: It's not a procedural language, agreed. But it does have a (standard) procedural extension (besides the many proprietary ones): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM

Comment: I suppose in a sense it could be interpreted as a programming language. Alright then let me say this: it is not a declarative language!

Comment: @Andrew it seems that at least one of the answers below must be working, if so, please mark one as correct (the hook left of the question) so this question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE Users
SET    `Downloads`='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4'
WHERE  `User`='andrewfree'
AND    NOT EXISTS(
           SELECT 1
           FROM   Users
           WHERE  Downloads='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4'
       )
```

---

Or add a unique key on Users.Downloads and use UPDATE IGNORE:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD UNIQUE KEY downloads_unique (Downloads);

UPDATE IGNORE Users SET Downloads = 'c63...' WHERE User='andrewfree';
```

If a row already exists with this `Downloads` value, the UPDATE will not be done.

> With the IGNORE keyword, [...] Rows for which duplicate-key conflicts occur are not updated.

See [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: mysql> UPDATE Users SET Downloads='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4' WHERE `User`='andrewfree' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Downloads='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4');  
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'Users' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Users 
SET `Downloads`='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4' 
WHERE `User`='andrewfree'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM Users 
              WHERE Downloads='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4')
```

EDIT:

Actually, the above statement will throw an error. I think this will do it (untested)

```
UPDATE Users u1 INNER JOIN Users u2 
                ON u2.Downloads='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4'
SET u1.`Downloads`='c6310e0ae33f9377f6ae7994bbafe6e20113aaf4' 
WHERE u1.`User`='andrewfree'
```